# How can I save data in Android Apps?

Tags: android, save

```
    fun loadData() {
        val sharedPref = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("MeineEinstellungen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val gson = Gson()
        val editor = sharedPref.edit()
        val json = sharedPref.getString("MeinSchlüssel", null)
        editor.putString("MeinSchlüssel", "Ihr Wert")
        editor.apply()

        // Wenn keine gespeicherte Liste gefunden wurde, initialisieren Sie items als eine leere Liste
        if (json != null) {
            val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
            items = gson.fromJson(json, type) // Konvertiert den JSON-String zurück in eine ArrayList
        } else {
            items = ArrayList()
        }
    }
    loadData()

    itemAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
    lvToDoList.adapter = itemAdapter
```

I want to save data in Android Studio. Here is my code, but when I call loadData() the program
cancels. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean "cancels"?  If you mean it crashes, post the stack trace.

Comment: can you please more elaborate this